# Determining portably the most restrictive data type for alignment

Tags: c, linux, alignment, posix

Choosing uintmax_t handles the integer case if I'm not overlooking something.

(1) Is there a similar such data type for floats, and, if yes, in which header? (it's not in float.h for me)

(2) is it correct that choosing a union of these 2 data types (assuming we can answer (1) in the affirmative) should always be most restrictive?

Comment: In "Determining portably", finding the most restrictive alignment on a _given_ platform may not solve the larger issue.  Maybe an example of code that uses "the most restrictive data type" would help?

Comment: @chux: take the old K&R final example in the book: re-creating malloc. The header of the linked list he uses is made to align to an arbitrarily chosen (in his case) "most restrictive alignment (long)." I'm currently reading Kerrisk TLIP, and an exercise is to again implement malloc. I meant to use the opportunity to make it as portable as possible, and align the list like this.

Comment: Thanks - Good that you are insuring alignment with `OP_malloc()` per §7.22.3 1 **Memory management functions** "... suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type of object with a fundamental alignment requirement ...".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in Eric's answer, C11 defines an object type with the greatest fundamental alignment in `<stddef.h>`: `max_align_t`.

Note, however, that this might not still work as expected on GCC. Taken from gcc's website:

> A fourth version of the C standard, known as C11, was published in
>   2011 as ISO/IEC 9899:2011. GCC has substantially complete support for
>   this standard, enabled with -std=c11 or -std=iso9899:2011. (While in
>   development, drafts of this standard version were referred to as C1X.)

If you don't want to rely on C11 due to its freshness and current lack of support, I suggest defining a union with all integer types, all floating point types, a void pointer, and a function pointer: one of these must be the most restrictive type.

Comment: Different pointer types are not required to have the same alignment requirements, although they will in most C implementations.

Comment: I'm on gcc 4.6.3, and -std=c11 is not recognized. If no one else points out something like (u)intmax_t for floats, I guess your suggested solution is the way to go.

Comment: @EricPostpischil true, but for the OP's purposes, it works: since any data pointer can be converted to `char *` (for historical reason) or `void *` and back safely, then these pointer types have the most stringent alignment requirements (section 6.1 on C: A Reference Manual confirms it)

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves: The fact that pointers can be converted to `void *` and back implies that `void *` contains all the information of the original. It implies nothing about alignment. E.g., consider an implementation with word-based memory in which a pointer to an `int` has only a word address and fits nicely in some memory unit. Then `int *` would have the alignment requirement of this memory unit. But `void *` would need a few extra bits. In this case, the implementation has to choose between aligning for two units (wasting memory) or using one-and-a-fraction units (costing performance).

Answer (score 2):

An object type with the greatest fundamental alignment supported by the implementation is `max_align_t`, defined in `<stddef.h>`.

I do not see text in the standard that specifies the alignment requirement of a union must be the strictest alignment requirement of its members. So, in theory, a union could require a stricter alignment than any of its members need. I see little reason for this and do not expect C implementations would do it. The usual case would be that the alignment requirement of a union is the strictest requirement of its members, unless the program explicitly requested greater alignment (as with the `_Alignas` keyword).

Comment: `max_align_t` comes from C11.

Comment: That would be perfect; but when I include stddef.h, then in a toy program declare one such variable and try to print it, gcc reports unknown type name error. Ideas?

Comment: @Palec: C is now C 2011; the 2011 standard “cancels and replaces the second edition, ISO/IEC 9899:1999”. If somebody wants to ask about prior versions of C, they should state that explicitly.

Comment: My glibc version is 2.15. Does that clarify if it supports C11? If not, how to check? Or OS there an alternative working under C99, if my system doesn't currently support C11?

Comment: @gnometorule If you're using gcc, try with -std=c11

Comment: That's an interesting point about a union's behavior to be undefined in this regard, but I agree with you that probably all implementations will act as I expected.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves, no don't use gcc with `-std=c11`. The C11 support is incomplete and gcc gives you no means detect the different C11 features that it supports.